# Find recommended videos per user with or without YouTube API

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

For a mobile application, I need to access the list of videos that YouTube recommends to each of my users.

However, the documentation on this matter in the YouTube API doesn't seem to be up-to-date; it states:

"... you can use the v3 API to find recommended videos by calling the activities.list method and setting the home parameter value to true."

Unfortunately, the home parameter has been deprecated. Consequently, I'm unsure if there is a current method to achieve what I'm looking for using the API. If not, are there alternative methods outside of the API?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what have you tried. Without any code, it's difficult to suggest alternatives

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.